# How to remove lines in pandas data frame based on specific character

Tags: python, pandas

I got this in my data frame

```
name : john,
address : Milton Kings,
phone : 43133241

Concern:
customer complaint about the services is so suck 

thank you
```

How can I process the above to remove only line of text in data frame containing `:`? My objective is to get the lines which contains the following only.

```
customer complaint about the services is so suck
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you explain the layout of the dataframe? What do you mean remove the "line of text"? If we're removing lines containing ':' then wouldn't the line you've provided also be removed?

Comment: You should think it twice, your text may have a `:`  in in it, for example "Concern: the costumer said: bla bla", if this is not a concern, the answers given already are good for it

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to separate the sentence after ':' from your data frame. And you can do this by creating a series from your data frame.

Let's say c is your series.

```
c=pd.Series(df['column'])
s=[c[i].split(':')[1] for i in range(len(c))]
```

By doing this you will be able to separate your sentence from colon.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the second part of the sentences, you can use the [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) 
 method to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

#Reproduce the dataframe
l = ["name : john",
"address : Milton Kings",
"phone : 43133241",
"Concern : customer complaint about the services is so suck" ]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)

#split on each element of the dataframe, and keep the second part
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(":")[1])
```

input :

```
    0
0   name : john
1   address : Milton Kings
2   phone : 43133241
3   Concern : customer complaint about the services is so suck
```

output :

```
    0
0    john
1    Milton Kings
2    43133241
3    customer complaint about the services is so suck
```